# How to get rss feed in XML format from webpages which end with .rss?

Tags: android, rss

I'm able to parse RSS feed which is in XML format from URL's like this in my Android app: http://techcrunch.com/feed/

How do I get RSS feed in XML format from URL's like this: http://timesofindia.feedsportal.com/c/33039/f/533968/index.rss?

Comment: what platform are you using? PHP? JAVA? iOS? Android? please be clear about your question

Comment: @VyrenMedia I'm using Android platform